# Consecutively update values starting from a number in the table SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a question regarding the usage of `UPDATE` statement. Is there a way for me to code the following scenario with only SQL instead of writing a stored procedure?

I tried to simplify the case.

`myTable` has 4 columns and its values are as follows:

```
COMP1   COMP2   NO  ACTIVE
0       0       4   N
4       1           Y
2       2       21  Y
3       1       1   Y
1       3       43  Y
2       1           Y
3       1       12  Y
2       2       0   Y
3       2           Y
1       1       5   N
```

- I want to select the values `WHERE ACTIVE = 'Y'` and start updating
  their values in NO column by ordering them by `COMP1, COMP2 ASC`.
- The numbering has to start from the `MAX(NO)` value in the table `WHERE ACTIVE = 'N'`
- The rows that have same COMP1 and COMP2 will have same NO values.
- (Update after comment) NO column is not always NULL. There are erroneous values in this column which are need to be corrected by the update query.

So that, after the `UPDATE` statement is executed, `myTable` will be as follows (if we order it)

```
COMP1   COMP2   NO  ACTIVE
0       0       4   N
1       1       5   N
1       3       6   Y
2       1       7   Y
2       2       8   Y
2       2       8   Y
3       1       9   Y
3       1       9   Y
3       2       10  Y
4       1       11  Y
```

I'm wondering if I would be able to do it without the need to select the whole list and looping in a CURSOR in a stored procedure.

(Update: I've written the SP. A simplified version is as follows. It may have problems since I changed all the names and deleted many conditions.)

```
 PROCEDURE updateAllNo
   IS
      CURSOR c1
      IS
           SELECT *
             FROM MyTable SE
            WHERE SE.ACTIVE = 'Y'
         ORDER BY SE.COMP1, SE.COMP2;

      v_last_no    NUMBER := 0;
      v_last_comp2   DATE := SYSDATE + 100;
      v_last_comp1   DATE := SYSDATE + 100;
      v_now_comp2    DATE := SYSDATE;
      v_now_comp1    DATE := SYSDATE;
   BEGIN
     SELECT MAX (SE.NO)
       INTO v_last_no
       FROM MyTable SE
      WHERE SE.ACTIVE = 'N';

     SELECT MAX (SE.COMP1), MAX (SE.COMP2)
       INTO v_last_comp1, v_last_comp2
       FROM MyTable SE
      WHERE     SE.ISLEMBASARILI = 'E'
            AND SE.NO = v_last_no;

     FOR r1 IN c1
     LOOP
        BEGIN
           v_now_comp2 := r1.COMP2;
           v_now_comp1 := r1.COMP1;

           IF v_now_comp2 != v_last_comp2 OR v_now_comp1 != v_last_comp1
           THEN
              v_last_no := v_last_no + 1;
           END IF;

           UPDATE MyTable SE
              SET SE.NO = v_last_no
            WHERE SEQ_ID = r1.seq_id;

           v_last_comp2 := v_now_comp2;
           v_last_comp1 := v_now_comp1;
        END;
     END LOOP;

     COMMIT;

   END;
```

I'm using Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new number can be retrieved using a window function:

The following will retrieve the active rows and calculate the new value for `no`

```
select comp1, 
       comp2,
       row_number() over (order by comp1, comp2) + (select max(no) from mytable where active = 'N') as rn
from mytable
where active = 'Y'
```

This can now be used in a `MERGE` statement to run an update against the table. As the table apparently has no PK, I will use the `ROWID` to match the rows:

```
merge into mytable tg
using (
    select rowid as rid,
           comp1, 
           comp2,
           row_number() over (order by comp1, comp2) + (select max(no) from mytable where active = 'N') as rn
    from mytable
    where active = 'Y'
) t on (t.rid = tg.rowid)
when matched then update
   set no = t.rn;
```

This will most definitely be faster than a loop with single row updates - especially for larger tables.

Comment: Thanks for this. It almost solved the problem except for cases where COMP1 = COMP2. I am also trying, but do you have any idea how can I set same NO for the rows that have same COMP1 and COMP2 as in my example. I guess, we need to write a CASE or something like that in the row_number() line.

Comment: @YigitalpErtem: the problem with `comp1 = comp2` can be solved by using `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`

Comment: Thank you so much. I need to learn the analytic functions, they seem powerful.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the field `NO` is always null when `ACTIVE='Y'`. If this is the case, then MAX(NO) will return the same value whether or not the `WHERE ACTIVE = 'N'` condition is specified. With this assumption, this `UPDATE` statement should do the trick.

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET NO = (SELECT MAX(NO) FROM myTable) + 1
WHERE ROWID IN 
(SELECT ROWID FROM myTable
WHERE ACTIVE = 'Y'
ORDER BY COMP1, COMP2);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But there are erroneous values in NO fields whose ACTIVE columns are 'Y', i.e. they are not always null. Update statement must correct these values and set the right numbers to NO column (I added this in the question). Also I tried your example, but it gave ORA-00934 error that does not let me to use the Group function.

Comment: I edited to take out the error. Still doesn't work for you, but I didn't wanna leave broken code here.